# Create PNG img & store it 64base encoded within <img> element in php

Tags: php

Hi why is this code to generate an image in php and set img src 64base encoded is not working?

I can not find the error:

```
//first code snipped - not working

ob_start();
$code = "3i23";
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165); //background color blue
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
//imagedestroy($im);
$imagedata = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imagedata).'"/>';
```

If I only want to generate the image with this snipped from above it would create an image:

```
//second code snipped - working - not usefull for me

$code = "3i23";
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165); //background color blue
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
//imagedestroy($im);
```

However I need to pass the image within a variable like it is shown in the first code snipped, but this is not working since it only shows an empty image.

Thanks for help

Comment: Whats not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Zachary without ob_start and ob_end_clean it works and echoing the img, the image is generated. Once I try top pass the image over ob_... to the html image it does not work at all.

Comment: Thats because your clearing the buffer with ob_end_clean() before using the image... the variable $imagedata will be empty after ob_end_clean

Comment: @Zachary yes thx but I also could write $imagedata = ob_get_clean(); and there would be still no image output for it. Do you know a solution?
I only want to show the image once I echo the img element. Thx

Comment: imagepng($im); will output the image directly

Comment: @Zachary thx I want to use it within the echo img 64base encoded. So a direct imagepng output will be no solution for me.

Comment: `header('Content-type: image/png');` makes no sense when you're echoing HTML (an `<img... />` tag). The content type tells the client what type of content it gets back so it will know how to handle it. If you say it's an image, then it will treat the full response as part of the image data (including the HTML part)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks I missed this part and it solved my question.